# Using literal underscore character in a MySQL query from c#

Tags: c#, mysql, escaping

From my ASP.NET application I want to issue this query to MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM responses WHERE field_id LIKE '3\_%'
```

In other words I am looking for records where the second character is the underscore literal character.

The code generated by the model designer looks like this:

```
    public virtual RiskAnalysis.responsesDataTable GetResponseGroupForAnalysis(int raid, string fieldid) {
    this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[2];
    this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[0].Value = ((int)(raid));
    if ((fieldid == null)) {
        throw new global::System.ArgumentNullException("fieldid");
    }
    else {
        this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[1].Value = ((string)(fieldid));
    }
    RiskAnalysis.responsesDataTable dataTable = new RiskAnalysis.responsesDataTable();
    this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
    return dataTable;
}
```

If I call this function like so:

```
string filter_string = @"3\_%";    
ResponsesAdapter.GetResponseGroupForAnalysis(10, filter_string);
```

the MySQL log reports the query to look like this:

```
SELECT     *
FROM         responses
WHERE     (ra_id = 10) AND (field_id LIKE '3\\_%')
```

In other words the I know I'm missing something blindingly obvious here, but how do I place MySQL's escape backslash in the query without C# (un)helpfully escaping it?

Comment: And if you would add another backslash in your c# code? I know it sounds counter-intuitive, but it might show the library that you want an actual backslash.

Comment: Then I get `SELECT * FROM responses WHERE (ra_id = 10) AND (field_id LIKE '3\\\\_%')` which would match records where field_id starts with 3\\[single character][0 or more characters]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems (by experiment - happy to hear explanation or documentation link) that in MySQL `(field_id LIKE '3\_%');` is equivalent to `(field_id LIKE '3\\_%');` and both will find records where field_id starts with '3_'. Got myself well confused there - thanks Mahmoud and René for trying to understand what I was getting at!

Answer (score 0):

In the standard SQL, you can use the `ESCAPE` keyword to set an escaping character.

MySQL follows the standard SQL in this, as stated by the `LIKE` predicate documentation:

- **[`expr LIKE pat [ESCAPE 'escape_char']`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)**

Like so:

```
...

field_id LIKE '3\_%' ESCAPE '\'
```

This will make the wildcard `_` be treated as a string literal.

Hope this what you were asking about.

Comment: I think you're suggesting I change the escape character from \ to something else that the C# @"..." syntax won't interfere with, but if possible I don't want to tamper with the generated queries.

Comment: @ChrisJones - No, this is the standard SQL way to do this. Just try it this way.